# Postgresql: Changing Action For Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a simple table like below.

```
create table chemlab.rule_header (
    id           serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name         varchar(50),
    grade        varchar(20),
    class_tag    varchar(20),    --tag added to sammple if match
    parent_id    int REFERENCES chemlab.rule_header(id) DEFAULT NULL,
    unique( grade, class_tag )
)
```

But afterwards, I found that I need to add `ON DELETE` action, the default is `NO ACTION`. I couldn't figure out how to change the action.

Now I have to `DROP` & `ADD`

```
ALTER table chemlab.rule_header 
    DROP CONSTRAINT rule_header_parent_id_fkey ;
ALTER TABLE rule_header  
    ADD CONSTRAINT rule_header_parent_id_fkey 
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES chemlab.rule_header(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

So what is the correct syntax to alter an action on foreign key constraint ?

Comment: Are you saying that dropping and adding doesn't work?

Comment: No its works, but I want to alter. I get all sort of errors "Syntax Error near ON" "near FOREIGN" ... Wasted an hour on this until giving up, can't help wondering what is the correct syntax to alter this thing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, this not directly altering FOREIGN KEY constraint, and there are `DROP` and `ADD` still, though this is only one statement:

```
ALTER table  chemlab.rule_header 
    DROP CONSTRAINT rule_header_parent_id_fkey,
    ADD CONSTRAINT rule_header_parent_id_fkey 
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES chemlab.rule_header(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: Thank you, Looks like you are right. There seems no way to alter constraints options.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html. There are options to alter a few things about a constraint (like DEFERRABLE) but not for changing the action, as I understand you need.

Comment: Is it planned in future to be able to modify a constraint's actions without dropping it ?

Still revelant problem nowadays. If I'm a bit distracted and forget to put CASCADE on both update and delete actions before filling everything else in the constraint, I kind of often forget it and end up having to do constraint all over again.